# Insert two TextFields in a column

Tags: flutter, dart

I already have one TextField and I would like to add another one but I am having a lot of trouble with it. I want it to be aligned in a column. The second TextField is pretty much like the one that is already written in the code below. To sum up, there should be two textfields, one above another in the center of the screen.

```
class _TelaPrincipalState extends State<TelaPrincipal> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 250.0,
            height: 80.0,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Insert first input',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
      
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with column used text controller

```
class _TelaPrincipalState extends State< TelaPrincipal> {
  final firstTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final secondTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
    ),

    body: Column(
       children: [
         TextField(
           controller: firstTextEditingController,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             labelText: 'Insert first input',
             fillColor: Colors.white,
             filled: true,
             contentPadding:
             EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
           ),
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
         ),

         TextField(
           controller: secondTextEditingController,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             labelText: 'Insert second input',
             fillColor: Colors.white,
             filled: true,
             contentPadding:
             EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
           ),
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
         )
       ],
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jahidul Islam, first of all, thank you for your solution! It solved most part of my problem but, since I am still a beginner, I am having trouble with putting these TextFields in two smaller containers (reducing the width) and centering it to the screen, could you give me a hand?